# Reshape 3D numpy array stack of images to vectors and back to 3D, preserving image structure

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, transpose

I observe the change from repeated imagery in time. I have a 3D numpy array, which should represent a stack of 2 images, each 3x3 px (for simplicity - shape: 2×3×3):

```
x = np.array([
    [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
    ],
    [
        [10,11,12],
        [13,14,15],
        [16,17,18]
    ]
])
```

I transposed and reshaped it such, that now I have "pixel vectors in time", like this:

```
y = x.transpose(2,1,0).reshape(-1, x.shape[0])

>>> array([[ 1, 10],
       [ 4, 13],
       [ 7, 16],
       [ 2, 11],
       [ 5, 14],
       [ 8, 17],
       [ 3, 12],
       [ 6, 15],
       [ 9, 18]])
```

I made a few scientific computations and ended up with Boolean values for each pixel vector, assessing certain characteristics:

```
>>> array([[ True, False, True],
       [ True, True, True],
       [False, False, True],
       [False, False, False],
       [ True, False, True],
       [ True, False, True],
       [ True, False, True],
       [ True, True, True],
       [False, False, True]])
```

Now, how do I reshape/transpose this array to a shape of (number of characteristics)×3×3 and preserve a logical order of pixels of a single image, as in array x?

I will try to clarify further if necessary.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `y` (not the mask) to verify that you successfully reconstruct `x`, but essentially, keep track of the shape of the intermediate array before reshaping, and just reshape back to that shape and transpose again:

```
y_t = x.transpose(2,1,0) # same as x.T
y = y_t.reshape(-1, x.shape[0])

y.reshape(y_t.shape).T
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]]])
```

Otherwise you can also just use the initial array's shape as a reference:

```
y = x.transpose(2,1,0).reshape(-1, x.shape[0])
y.reshape(x.shape[::-1]).T
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 7,  8,  9]],

       [[10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18]]])
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that I can verify against `y` only after I posted the question. And thanks! I came up with another solution in the meantime, something like this: `characteristics.reshape(characteristics.shape[0], x.shape[1], x.shape[2]).swapaxes(1,2)`